# Ruby doesn't work on Mac after installed with Brew

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, homebrew

I'm on Mac with OS X El Capitan. I installed ruby with `brew install ruby` in the terminal, but when I type `ruby -v` or `ruby --version`, nothing came up. If I run a simple ruby file with output, nothing showed either. I tried to use `binding.pry` to stop the script, but it didn't stop and nothing showed in the terminal. I thought the install wasn't successful but when I run `brew install ruby` again, I says "ruby-2.3.0 already installed". I wonder what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

in `~/.bash_profile` add the following line

```
export PATH="$(brew --prefix)/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
```

When you're done, close your terminal and re-open it. You should be fine.

Or if you don't want to re-open your terminal, you can do this:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

I suggest that you should install `ruby` via `rvm` or `rbenv`.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove ruby from homebrew and suggest installing either rbenv (https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) or rvm (https://rvm.io/) with brew (rbenv is my preferred).

This way you can have multiple versions of ruby on your system at any time and switch between which version you want for different projects.  It is quite nice.